# Redirecting to a web without changing the URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

I wants to redirect my users who opens my web page to a new page but i also wants that if the user see the URL of the page in the url bar then the url of the first page should be visible.
For example,let i have a web named http://example.com and i wants that every users that visits should be redirected to http://google.com but also when he see the URL of the page in the URL bar then it should show example.com.
I there's any way to does it?

Comment: You mean you want to iframe other websites and claim them as your own? Simple, just an iframe **but** some websites don't allow you to iframe them, example: youtube / facebook. They have their own API for extracting data and submitting.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an iframe which can load any website inside of it.  For your question you will need to add the following code to your page:

`<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>`

You can then adjust other attributes of the iframe with width, height, etc.

More information on available attributes for the iframe element can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Alternatively, If you have access to your DNS provider and your DNS provider supports it, you may also be able to use domain masking.

Domain masking, means that visitors to your website will only see the domain name (or URL) they typed in the address bar of their browser, not the domain name where you have forwarded them.

Specific instructions on how to do this cannot be given without knowing who your DNS provider is.